# ¿Como podría programar de forma mas eficiente?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

excelente día, tengo un código en el cual repito muchas veces el mismo proceso, ya definí una función, sin embargo, aún así el código es extenso.

Esta es una de las funciones declaradas.

```
def Convolucion(ImpulsoL, ImpulsoR, Audio):
      ConvL = signal.fftconvolve(Audio,ImpulsoL,mode='full')
      ConvR = signal.fftconvolve(Audio,ImpulsoR,mode='full')
      return ConvL, ConvR
```

Y aquí es donde llamó a esa función, sin embargo, este proceso se debe repetir 74 veces.

```
[Convolu1L, Convolu1R] = Convolucion(Impulso1L, Impulso1R, CanalAmbisonics)
[Convolu2L, Convolu2R] = Convolucion(Impulso2L, Impulso2R, CanalAmbisonics)
[Convolu3L, Convolu3R] = Convolucion(Impulso3L, Impulso3R, CanalAmbisonics)
[Convolu4L, Convolu4R] = Convolucion(Impulso4L, Impulso4R, CanalAmbisonics)
.
.
.
[Convolu74L, Convolu74R] = Convolucion(Impulso37R, Impulso37L, CanalAmbisonics)
```

No anexo todo el código por que es muy extenso.

Comment: Pues depende mucho de cómo obtengas las variables `ImpulsoXL` e `ImpulsoXR`. Lo más seguro es que en algún punto puedas añadir un loop que te lo vaya haciendo y metiendo los resultados en una lista de tuplas

Comment: También puedes usar arreglos para guardar los parámetros y los resultados de la función. El código se reduce a iterar sobre el arreglo, extrayendo parámetros, llamando a la función, almacenando resultados en otro arreglo. Un arreglo te será más fácil de manejar después

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para eso se inventaron los arreglos.

Dado que no tengo el modulo `signal`, voy a maquetear la función `Convolución`, que se limitar a retornar un par de valores aleatorios:

```
def Convolucion(ImpulsoL, ImpulsoR, Audio):
    ConvL = random.random()
    ConvR = random.random()
    return ConvL, ConvR
```

Ahora al problema.

Primero definimos un arreglo con los parámetros a usar en la llamada a `Convolucion`. Voy a suponer que estos son valores decimales para efectos de la demo.

Cada elemento de `parametros` es un par de valores correspondientes a `ImpulsoNL` e `ImpulsoRL`. Estos valores pueden venir de otro proceso, ser leídos de un archivo, desde una URL, o ser codificados a mano, como ahora:

```
parametros = [
    # (ImpulsoxL, ImpulsoxR)
    (0.34, .33),
    (0.40, .42),
    (0.45, .45),
    (0.42, .30),
]

resultados = []
```

También tengo un arreglo para recoger los resultados.

Ahora sólo me queda recorrer el arreglo de parámetros y llamar a la función, almacenando los resultados:

```
for param in parametros:
    conv = Convolucion(param[0], param[1], 1)
    resultados.append(conv)

for r in resultados:
    print(r[0], r[1])
```

produce:

```
0.22472887242510875 0.7927693537353863
0.8060637362583836 0.29714972846006904
0.5225614276962511 0.08289884727401708
0.9673316051248433 0.6359217957284866
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, excelente ayuda.